# Email migrations from office 365 to gsuite

Tags: email, migration, google, office365

**Want I want to do:** I want to migrate emails from office 365 to Google suite, is it possible that I add the same domain to Google suite, create the users' emails before I begin migrating? Without interrupting email flow of course?

**Things I have realized at the moment:**
- Our former IT admin had used a different DNS server which was added to the office 365 setup seems it's from Go daddy not so sure thou.

**What I've done, and still trying to do**
- I've got another DNS zone on hosting for Africa where the domain was purchased, tried to verify/add the domain on Google suite using the TXT or CNAME, which has actually been failing.

I don't want to disrupt email inflow, that is why I'm hesitating to update the DNS record. Some of the things I've said here are actually assumptions as I'm trying this for the first time and don't fully understand how the things work.

But I feel with the MX record intact the emails won't stop flowing. Please, how do I go about this?

Comment: `is it possible that I add the same domain to Google suite, create the users' emails before I begin migrating? Without interrupting email flow of course?` - Yes. Make sure you don't change your MX record until you're ready to cut over to GSuite.

Comment: Check the manual https://support.google.com/a/answer/6351465?hl=en

Comment: @joeqwerty what if I had updated the MX record before migration, will the old emails still remain on outlook's server and then decide to move them at a much later time? I feel it makes sense for them to remain... I'm just trying to confirm. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, any email that already exists at the old server would remain there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Creating users before migration

Yes you can do this easily, you can setup and validate the domain before you make any changes to mailflow.

For an Office 365 to GSuite migration the primary change to mailflow will happen in the form of a change to the domains MX record.

You can add your domain to Gsuite, configure all the users on the solution and validate your domain. All this has no effect on any current system since Gsuite always resolves using MX records, so other Gsuite/Gmail users will keep sending mails to Office 365 while you configure the solution until you actually change the MX record.

#### 2. Validating domain things

You can have your domain added to multiple different DNS hosting providers, however only the one you have told your domain registrar is your NameServers will actually have any effect on the rest of the world.

If you are in doubt which NameServers are currently controlling DNS for your domain, you can do a WhoIs lookup to find the NameServers and thus know which provider you should be making changes for DNS to.

As for validating the domain in Google, simply create a new TXT record with the DNS provider that matches googles description, a simple DNS record has no effect on anything and is used for a 1 time validation, so you cannot mess with any other system while doing this :)